# How do I define the size of a CollectionView on rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a viewcontroller with 2 CollectionView Controllers.

I would like on rotation that only one of the collection views resize to a custom size while the other remains the same.

I have tried to use:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout  *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {    
     // Adjust cell size for orientation
     if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
        return CGSizeMake(170.f, 170.f);
     }
    return CGSizeMake(192.f, 192.f);
}
```

However that just changes both collectionviews. How do I get it to be specific to only one collection?

Comment: looks like it should work on iOS11 without any tricks

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Heres my 2 cents - because your item sizes are static why don't you set the item size on the `collectionViewLayout`?

It will be quicker to do this rather than expecting the collection view to call its delegate method for every cell.

`viewWillLayoutSubviews` can be used for detection of rotation on view controllers.
`invalidateLayout` can be used on a collection view layout to force it to prepare the layout again causing it to position the elements with the new sizes in this case.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews;
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (id)self.firstCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarOrientation)) {
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(170.f, 170.f);
    } else {
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(192.f, 192.f);
    }

    [flowLayout invalidateLayout]; //force the elements to get laid out again with the new size
}
```

**edit: updated with Swift2.0 example**

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

  guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
    return
  }

  if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 170, height: 170)
  } else {
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 192, height: 192)
  }

  flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: This works however I am now getting a warning that states:
 Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout *' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewLayout *'

Comment: you will need to cast the collectionViewLayout, i will adjust the answer now @RobertFarr

Comment: @OliverAtkinson tks. it's already worked with my app. but what is happen when in each cell, i have 1 imageview? after resize collection view cell, but image did'nt load, i have to reload or swipe left / right to get image update. how can i update/ reload these imageview ?

Comment: @TomSawyer you can use reloadItemsAtIndexPath if the data has changed - but rotation should not affect the underlying data and should not require a reload of the data if it is already there.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson I've changed itemSize after rotate but imageview in cell will not fit with new itemSize. Here is screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dEjY8.png , so, i have to swipe left / right to update imageView or use collectionView.reloadData() to get imageView fit with new cell itemSize like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/XB9AA.jpg . Any better way to solve it , i heard about constraint ?

Comment: Are you using autolayout? make the imageView leading and trailing constraints to the superview - or if not turn all its autoresizing masks on and make it the full size of the cell

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Answer (score 49):

With new API since **iOS 8** I'm using:

Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    updateCollectionViewLayout(with: size)
}

private func updateCollectionViewLayout(with size: CGSize) {
    if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.itemSize = (size.width < size.height) ? itemSizeForPortraitMode : itemSizeForLandscapeMode
        layout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
        [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
        [self updateCollectionViewLayoutWithSize:size];
}

- (void)updateCollectionViewLayoutWithSize:(CGSize)size {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        layout.itemSize = (size.width < size.height) ? itemSizeForPortraitMode : itemSizeForLandscapeMode;
        [layout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

***The Verified Answer Is Not Efficient***

**The Problem** - Invalidating the layout in *viewWillLayoutSubviews()* is heavy work.  *viewWillLayoutSubviews()* gets called multiple times when a *ViewController* is instantiated.

**My Solution (Swift)** - Embed your size manipulation within the *UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout*.

```
// Keep a local property that we will always update with the latest 
// view size.
var updatedSize: CGSize!

// Use the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to set the size of our        
// cells.
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // We will set our updateSize value if it's nil.
    if updateSize == nil {
        // At this point, the correct ViewController frame is set.
        self.updateSize = self.view.frame.size
    }

    // If your collectionView is full screen, you can use the 
    // frame size to judge whether you're in landscape.
    if self.updateSize.width > self.updateSize.height {
        return CGSize(width: 170, 170)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 192, 192)
    }
}

// Finally, update the size of the updateSize property, every time 
// viewWillTransitionToSize is called.  Then performBatchUpdates to
// adjust our layout.
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    self.updateSize = size
    self.collectionView!.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Instead of saving the size and calling performBatchUpdates, all you need to do is call  self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() Then in sizeForItemAtIndexPath simply get the new bounds from the view/collectionView

Answer (score 3):

You can change your if statement. You will need to have a reference to the collection views

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) && collectionView == self.firstCollectionView) {
   return CGSizeMake(170.f, 170.f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question was , how to separate two collection views in sizeForItemAtIndexPath.
Why just not something like this?

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if collectionView == firstCollectionView{

            return CGSize(width: self.frame.width/3, height: 40)
       }


    else if collectionView == secondCollectionView{

        return CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height-2)
    }

    abort()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by checking the rotation of the device and then reloading the layout. Checking the screen size and using this size to display my cell.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    //get new width of the screen
    screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    //if landscape mode
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        screenDivide = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        screenDivide = 3;
    }

    //reload the collectionview layout after rotating
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    [layout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Then I defined the cells like this

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    CGSize elementSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth/screenDivide, 100);
    return elementSize;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've handled this by detecting the orientation change in the `setBounds:` method.  We subclass the `UICollectionView` and override the `setBounds:` method (see below).  In `flowLayoutForGallerySize` we create a new `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with different spacing and itemSize depending on the size of the collection view.

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    // detect orientation changes and update itemSize in the flow layout
    CGSize oldSize = self.bounds.size;

    [super setBounds:bounds];

    BOOL wasLandscape = (oldSize.width > oldSize.height);
    BOOL nowLandscape = (bounds.size.width > bounds.size.height);

    if (wasLandscape != nowLandscape) {
        // create a new flow layout object for the new gallery size
        self.flowLayout = [self flowLayoutForGallerySize:bounds.size];

        // change to the new flow layout
        [self setCollectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout animated:NO];

        DLog(@"orientation change to %@", NSStringFromCGSize(bounds.size));
    }
}
```

Comment: The code I posted works fine for resizing, however I want it to only resize one of the 2 seperate collection views

Comment: Why don't you just look at the collectionView: parameter to see which one is being passed in and only apply it when its the right one??