# Set collection view cell size relative to screen size swift

Tags: ios, swift, resize, uicollectionviewcell, uitraitcollection

I am Trying to resize my cell based on the screen size so that there is only 2 cell per row. I am using the code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: MyCollectionView.bounds.width / 2.2, height: MyCollectionView.bounds.height / 5.5)    
}
```

This works and resizes to the different screen sizes. I run it on. however when you rotate into landscape mode it displays more than two cells per row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView - resizing cells on device rotate - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132766/uicollectionview-resizing-cells-on-device-rotate-swift)

Answer (score 0):

If The container of MyCollectionView is self.view then plz give a try to  this . .

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width / 2.2 , height: MyCollectionView.bounds.height / 5.5)
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it looks great in portrait but still displays more cells in landscape