# TableView Section Footers doesn't resize its width after rotation

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a table view with header and footer in every section.
When the device rotates, the headers resizes to fit the table's width, but the footers remains with portrait width.

I tried setting a large width in the xib file, and it works for the header, but no effect on footer.

I also tried doing a reload data in

```
viewWillTransitionToSize
```

and it works, but I feel like is not the best way to do it, it also has a weird animation while rotating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, with estimatedRowHeight.
I don't know why but after that, the footer resized properly.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132766/uicollectionview-resizing-cells-on-device-rotate-swift) should be helpful but this is bassically called whenever the view controller views is about to layout its subviews.

So your code will look like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
   if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {
      //here you can do the logic for the cell size if phone is in landscape
   } else {
         //logic if not landscape 
     }
 self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Any idea why `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is triggered over and over again if I set the `tableView.ContentSize` to some arbitrary value inside the same method?