# Dynamic-height UICollectionView inside a dynamic-height UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal `UICollectionView` pinned to all edges of a `UITableViewCell`. Items in the collection view are dynamically sized, and I want to make the table view's height equal to that of the tallest collection view cell.

The views are structured as follows:

> UITableView
>
> > UITableViewCell
> >
> > > UICollectionView
> > >
> > > > UICollectionViewCell
> > > >
> > > > UICollectionViewCell
> > > >
> > > > UICollectionViewCell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return collectionView
    }()

    var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 20)
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        return layout
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: CollectionViewCell.self), bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCellModel.identifier)

        addSubview(collectionView)

        // (using SnapKit)
        collectionView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: targetSize.width , height: 1)

        return layout.collectionViewContentSize
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let spacing: CGFloat = 50
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: spacing, bottom: 0, right: spacing)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
    }
}


class OptionsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

        return contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: targetSize.width, height: 1))
    }
}

class CollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 500
    private var contentWidth: CGFloat = 200

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        if let attrs = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) {
           // perform some logic
           contentHeight = /* something */
           contentWidth = /* something */
           return attrs
        }
        return nil
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }
}
```

In my `UIViewController`, I have `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`.

I'm trying to make the table view cell's size in `systemLayoutSizeFitting` equal to the `collectionViewContentSize`, but it's called before the layout has had a chance to set `collectionViewContentSize` to the correct value. Here's the order in which these methods are called:

```
cellForRowAt
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (200.0, 500.0) << incorrect/original value
**OptionsTableViewCell systemLayoutSizeFitting (200.0, 500.0) << incorrect/original value**
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (200.0, 500.0) << incorrect/original value
willDisplay cell
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (200.0, 500.0) << incorrect/original value
TableViewCell layoutSubviews() collectionViewContentSize.height:  500.0 << incorrect/original value
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (200.0, 500.0) << incorrect/original value
CollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForElements
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (450.0, 20.0)
CollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForElements
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (450.0, 20.0)
CollectionViewCell systemLayoutSizeFitting
CollectionViewCell systemLayoutSizeFitting
CollectionViewCell systemLayoutSizeFitting
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (450.0, 20.0)
CollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForElements
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (450.0, 301.0) << correct size
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (450.0, 301.0) << correct size
TableViewCell layoutSubviews() collectionViewContentSize.height:  301.0 << correct height
CollectionViewFlowLayout layoutAttributesForElements
CollectionViewFlowLayout collectionViewContentSize:  (450.0, 301.0) << correct size
TableViewCell layoutSubviews() collectionViewContentSize.height:  301.0 << correct height
```

How can I make my table view cell's height equal to my collection view's tallest item, represented by the layout's `collectionViewContentSize`?

Comment: you need to calculate all cells height first to find the tallest one! That could have performance issues. And maybe it contains a cell that is taller than the entire tableview. Do you mind?

Answer (score 18):

There are some steps to achieve this:

- Defining selfsizing `UICollectionViewCell`
- Defining selfsizing `UICollectionView`
- Defining selfsizing `UITableViewCell`
- Calculate all cell sizes and find the tallest (Could be expensive)
- Reload higher order view of any child's `bounds` changed

### - Defining selfsizing `UICollectionViewCell`

You have two options here:
- use autolayout with selfsizing UI elements (like `UIImageView` or `UILabel` or etc.)
- calculate and provide it's size your self

-
**Use autolayout with selfsizing UI elements:**

if you set the `estimatedItemsSize` to be `automatic` and layout cell subviews correctly with selfsizing UI elements, it would be automatically sizing on the fly. **BUT** be aware of expensive layout time and lags because of complex layouts. Specially on older devices.

-
**Calculate and provide it's size your self:**

One of the best places that you can setup the cell size is `intrinsicContentSize`. Although there are other places to do this (eg. in flowLayout class or etc), this is were you can guarantee that cell will not conflict with other selfsizing UI elements:

```
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { return /*CGSize you prefered*/ }
```

### - Defining selfsizing `UICollectionView`

Any `UIScrollView` subclass can be selfsizing duo to it's `contentSize`. Since collectionView and tableView content sizes are constantly changing, you should inform the `layouter` (not known as layouter anywhere officially):

```
protocol CollectionViewSelfSizingDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didChageContentSizeFrom oldSize: CGSize, to newSize: CGSize)
}

class SelfSizingCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    weak var selfSizingDelegate: CollectionViewSelfSizingDelegate?

    override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if let floawLayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            floawLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        } else {
            assertionFailure("Collection view layout is not flow layout. SelfSizing may not work")
        }
    }

    override open var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            guard bounds.size.height != contentSize.height else { return }
            frame.size.height = contentSize.height
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

            selfSizingDelegate?.collectionView(self, didChageContentSizeFrom: oldValue, to: contentSize)
        }
    }
}
```

So after overriding `intrinsicContentSize` we observe for changes of contentSize and inform the `selfSizingDelegate` that will need to know about this.

### - Defining selfsizing `UITableViewCell`

This cells can be selfsizing by implementing this in their `tableView`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

We will put a `selfSizingCollectionView` in this cell and implement this:

```
class SelfSizingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: SelfSizingCollectionView!

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        ...
        collectionView.selfSizingDelegate = self
    }
}
```

So we conform the delegate and implement the function to update cell.

```
extension SelfSizingTableViewCell: CollectionViewSelfSizingDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didChageContentSizeFrom oldSize: CGSize, to newSize: CGSize) {
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView?.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        } else {
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I wrote some helper extensions for `UIView` and `UITableViewCell` to access parent table view:

```
extension UIView {

    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell {

    var tableView: UITableView? {
        return (next as? UITableView) ?? (parentViewController as? UITableViewController)?.tableView
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return tableView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```

To this point, your collection view will have exactly needed height (if it is vertical) but you should remember to limit all cell widths in order to not goes beyond screen width.

```
extension SelfSizingTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: heights[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Notice `heights` ? this is where you should cache (manual/automatic) calculated height of all cells in order to not getting laggy. (I generate all of them randomly for testing purposes)

### - Last two steps:

Last two steps are already covered but you should consider some important things about the case you seek:

1 - Autolayout could be epic performance killer if you ask it to calculate all cellsizes for you, but it's reliable.

2 - You must cache all sizes and get the tallest and return it in `tableView(:,heightForRowAt:)` (No more need for selfsizing `tableViewCell`)

3 - Consider the tallest one could be taller than entire `tableView` and 2D scrolling would be strange.

4 - If you reuse a cell containing a `collectionView` or `tableView`, the scroll offset, inset and many other attributes behave strange the way you're not expecting.

This is one of the most complex layouts of all you could meet, but once you get used to it, it become simple.

Comment: Hi @Mojtaba Hosseini, I have one label too above UICollectionview. In this case how can I calculate height.

Comment: Please test your way and ask a new question. It’s against guidelines of so to ask and answer questions in comments.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to achieve exactly what you want to do with a height constraint reference for the CollectionView (however I don't use SnapKit, neither programaticUI).

Here is how I did, it may help:

1. First I register a `NSLayoutConstraint` for the UICollectionView, which already has a `topAnchor` and a `bottomAnchor` equal to its superview

   [image: height constraint on UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell]

   ```
   class ChatButtonsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

       @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
       @IBOutlet weak var buttonsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
       @IBOutlet weak var buttonsCollectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // reference

   }
   ```
2. Then in my `UITableViewDelegate` implementation, on cellForRowAt, I set the height constraint's constant equal to the actuall collectionView frame like so :

   ```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // let item = items[indexPath.section]
        let item = groupedItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ChatButtonsTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ChatButtonsTableViewCell

        cell.chatMessage = nil // reusability 
        cell.buttonsCollectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.buttonsCollectionView.reloadData() // load actual content of embedded CollectionView
        cell.chatMessage = groupedItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? ChatMessageViewModelChoicesItem


        // >>> Compute actual height 
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        let height: CGFloat = cell.buttonsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        cell.buttonsCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
        // <<<

        return cell

    }
   ```

My assumption is that you could use this methodology to set you collectionView's height to the height of the biggest cell, replacing `let height: CGFloat = cell.buttonsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height` with the actual height you want.

Plus, if you are using an horizontal UICollectionView, my guess is that you don't even have to change this line, considering that the contentSize.height will be equal to your biggest cell height.

It works flawlessly for me, hope it helps

**EDIT**

Just thinking, you may need to place some `layoutIfNeeded()` and `invalidateLayout()` here and there. If it doesn't work straight away I can tell you where I put these.

**EDIT 2**

Also forgot to mention that I implemented `willDisplay` and `estimatedHeightForRowAt`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if let buttonCell = cell as? ChatButtonsTableViewCell {
        cellHeights[indexPath] = buttonCell.buttonsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    } else {
        cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 70.0
}
```

Comment: Seems as if AutoLayout is unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. There is a UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height constraint conflicting with the `buttonsCollectionViewHeightConstraint`. I don't think it's safe to change the height constraint from `cellForRowAt`. If it works for you, would you mind linking to a GitHub?

Comment: This is a project I did for a company I cant link the repo to you. However, try to lower the priority of the ButtonsCollectionViewHeightConstraint to 999 instead of 1000. as you can see on the screenshoot I sent, the constraint is dotted, which indicates it as a lower priority. Give it a try. ( .source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795758/5464805 )

Comment: I can't set the `buttonsCollectionViewHeightConstraint` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt)` because that is called well before the collection view cell gets a chance to draw its bounds correctly.

Comment: Just edited my answer. I forgot that I implemented willDisplay and estimatedHeightForRowAt.

Comment: `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt)` and `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)` are also called before the collection view cell lays out. `cellHeights` only helps after scrolling through the table view to populate the array; it's not as helpful the first time each table view cell lays out because waiting to reset the row height after its collection view layout can calculate a height produces jerkiness.

Comment: I remember passing through all these issues... I am trying to figure out the chunck of code that fixes everything in my project

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work in your code because cell's `systemLayoutSizeFitting` was called before `collectionView` finished laying out. To make it work, you need to update table view layout when collectionView is done laying out.

I wrote detailed instructions on how to do [self sizing with collection view inside table view cell here](https://viet-tran.medium.com/uicollectionview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-with-self-sizing-beccb6de4159). I also include [sample codes here](https://github.com/viettran/CollectionViewTableCell). Below is the gist of it:

1. Capture event when collection view is done laying out. If you subclass `UICollectionView`, override `layoutSubviews`. If you subclass `UIViewController` or `UICollectionViewController`, override `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
2. Hook up this event handler to table view cell to update table view layout when collection view finishes laying out.
3. Override `systemLayoutSizeFitting` in table view cell to return collection view's `contentSize`, which you already did.
4. Don't reload the table rows while you only need to update its layout (automatic height). I see some answers here suggesting reloadData or reloadRows. If your collection view is heavy, don't do it. A simple `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` will update row heights without reloading the rows.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    //  Set this action during initialization to get a callback when the collection view finishes its layout.
    //  To prevent infinite loop, this action should be called only once. Once it is called, it resets itself
    //  to nil.
    var didLayoutAction: (() -> Void)?
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        didLayoutAction?()
        didLayoutAction = nil   //  Call only once
    }
}
```

```
class CollectionViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var collectionViewController: CollectionViewController!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        collectionViewController = CollectionViewController(nibName: String(describing: CollectionViewController.self), bundle: nil)
        
        //  Need to update row height when collection view finishes its layout.
        collectionViewController.didLayoutAction = updateRowHeight
        
        contentView.addSubview(collectionViewController.view)
        collectionViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            collectionViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            collectionViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            collectionViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func updateRowHeight() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.tableView?.updateRowHeightsWithoutReloadingRows()
        }
    }
}
```

```
extension UITableView {
    func updateRowHeightsWithoutReloadingRows(animated: Bool = false) {
        let block = {
            self.beginUpdates()
            self.endUpdates()
        }
        
        if animated {
            block()
        }
        else {
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                block()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell {
    var tableView: UITableView? {
        return (next as? UITableView) ?? (parentViewController as? UITableViewController)?.tableView
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIViewController {
            return nextResponder
        } else if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIView {
            return nextResponder.parentViewController
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that if your app target is iOS 14, consider the new [UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionlayoutlistconfiguration). It makes collection view layout just like table view row. Here is the [WWDC-20 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10026/) that shows how to do it.

Comment: Is there a version of this where each row is a Collection View & it's from data loaded from something like Firebase? I've tried using your code example & I do see my data but it's not sizing properly.

Comment: This is 100% correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem a couple of days ago, getting the correct height of a `UICollectionView` within a `UITableViewCell`. None of the solutions worked. I finally found a solution for [resizing cells on device rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56618052/2707207)

In short, I update the table view with the function:

```
- (void) reloadTableViewSilently {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self.tableView beginUpdates];
      [self.tableView endUpdates];
   });
}
```

The function is called in `viewWillAppear` and in `viewWillTransitionToSize: withTransitionCoordinator`

Works like a charm even for device rotation. Hope this helps.